# Uneven usage of RAM across nodes in Couchbase cluster

Tags: memory, couchbase, ram

```
couchbase-server-community         4.0.0-4051-1
```

We have a Couchbase cluster of 21 nodes and around 150 client boxes connect to this cluster. I see some boxes have RAM usage of 91%, while others are using only 66%, is there any way to ensure more distributed usage of RAM. Most of the RAM in all the boxes are being taken by `/opt/couchbase/bin/memcached`, following are two examples of RAM usage from two extreme boxes:

box with less memory usage:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
999       4345 62.5 61.9 36074956 33934188 ?   Ssl  Feb01 27737:28 /opt/couchbase/bin/memcached -C /opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/config/memcached.json
999       4216 52.8  2.4 1840896 1314404 ?     Ssl  Feb01 23450:08 /opt/couchbase/lib/erlang/erts-5.10.4.0.0.1/bin/beam.smp -A 16 -sbt u -P 327680 -K true -swt low -MMmcs 30 -e102400 -- -root /opt/couchbase/lib/erlang -progname erl -- -home /opt/couchbase -- -smp enable -setcookie nocookie -kernel inet_dist_listen_min 21100 inet_dist_listen_max 21299 error_logger false -sasl sasl_error_logger false -nouser -run child_erlang child_start ns_bootstrap -- -smp enable -couch_ini /opt/couchbase/etc/couchdb/default.ini /opt/couchbase/etc/couchdb/default.d/capi.ini /opt/couchbase/etc/couchdb/default.d/geocouch.ini /opt/couchbase/etc/couchdb/local.ini
999       9920  1.1  0.1 595164 105572 ?       Sl   Feb01 500:35 /opt/couchbase/bin/indexer -vbuckets=1024 -cluster=127.0.0.1:8091 -adminPort=9100 -scanPort=9101 -httpPort=9102 -streamInitPort=9103 -streamCatchupPort=9104 -streamMaintPort=9105 -storageDir=/storage/1/couchbase/index/@2i
```

box with high memory usage:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
999      20812 71.1 85.0 48014804 46535824 ?   Ssl   2017 568761:06 /opt/couchbase/bin/memcached -C /opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/config/memcached.json
999      20690 52.8  5.2 3564552 2863852 ?     Ssl   2017 422691:18 /opt/couchbase/lib/erlang/erts-5.10.4.0.0.1/bin/beam.smp -A 16 -sbt u -P 327680 -K true -swt low -MMmcs 30 -e102400 -- -root /opt/couchbase/lib/erlang -progname erl -- -home /opt/couchbase -- -smp enable -setcookie nocookie -kernel inet_dist_listen_min 21100 inet_dist_listen_max 21299 error_logger false -sasl sasl_error_logger false -nouser -run child_erlang child_start ns_bootstrap -- -smp enable -couch_ini /opt/couchbase/etc/couchdb/default.ini /opt/couchbase/etc/couchdb/default.d/capi.ini /opt/couchbase/etc/couchdb/default.d/geocouch.ini /opt/couchbase/etc/couchdb/local.ini
999      21421  0.8  0.4 2914624 242084 ?      Sl    2017 6439:31 /opt/couchbase/bin/cbq-engine --datastore=http://127.0.0.1:8091 --http=:8093 --configstore=http://127.0.0.1:8091 --enterprise=false
999      21395  4.0  0.4 1063508 223060 ?      Sl    2017 32088:04 /opt/couchbase/bin/projector -kvaddrs=127.0.0.1:11210 -adminport=:9999 127.0.0.1:8091
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On a first sight, it seems to be still OK to me. It's hard to tell without knowing which kind of workload you are running. Memcached is a memory cache.

Maybe the nodes with more utilized memory recently processed more memory-consuming workload that is cached at the moment.

Maybe the nodes consuming more memory are just running for longer time (memcached keeps objects in memory forever till they are not evicted by reaching mem quota).

Maybe your 150 clients are unable to fully utilize your 21 cluster nodes (Why 1 node per ~7,14 clients?)

Comment: What do you mean by `150 clients are unable to fully utilize your 21 cluster`, so from one client(one box running my application), there will be many connections connecting to these boxes, We had to increase the couchbase boxes as data increased.

Comment: Also I would like to have memory usage more uniform, as few boxes have no free RAM available, as around 93+% memory is used by these processes itself.